# Error inflating class fragment (As ListFragment)

Tags: android

I get the following error while trying to create a ListFragment in a tab.
I just want to have a list in that fragment, nothing special.. I'am sorry that this is more a lack of knowledge than a bug, but i hung on this problem for 2 days now and don't know what i shall do else then ask you guys. Thx.

```
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com..bucp/com..bucp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class fragment
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class fragment
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at com..bucp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    ... 11 more
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com..bucp.BanlistFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
07-07 13:08:18.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19662):    ... 25 more
```

The given line #63 is the tag of the Fragment:

```
<fragment        
android:name="com..bucp.BanlistFragment"
android:id="@+id/banl_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/banlist_fragment" />
```

The fragment file itselve contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the fragment class just contains

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    getActivity(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    month);
  setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View tmp_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banlist_fragment, container, false);
     ListView list = (ListView) tmp_view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  return list;
 }
```

Comment: provide BanlistFragment complete file (from first line from package com.fr34kyd3v.bucp).....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in stack trace you have: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fr34kyd3v.bucp.BanlistFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment`

I'm guessing, maybe your BanlistFragment class extends Fragment from support library (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) and activity tries to "handle it natively" not with support library? 
To get sth more than guess provide source code for BanlistFragment.

Answer (score 1):

point -1

It think it should be like as and BanlistFragment should extends Fragment

```
  @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View tmp_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banlist_fragment, container, false);
         ListView list = (ListView) tmp_view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
      return tmp_view; //<------------------------------
     }
```

point -2

as pet life cycle http://developer.android.com/images/activity_fragment_lifecycle.png  onCreate get called before onCreateView so

```
setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

should be in onCreateView or function get called after this...

Comment: Well, my idea was to extend a ListFragment to get "setListAdapter" "onListItemClick" and "getListView" ... These are function which are only avaiable in that class.. ListFragment does extend Fragment~thats why i dont get why it it isnt working.. YOu were right with the retuen / but the error is still there

Comment: please provide BanlistFragment complete file (from first line from package com.fr34kyd3v.bucp).

Comment: Thank you but the code was right, it was indeed a problem with the includes.